# Android WebView open html page from WebView html

Tags: android, html, android-studio, webview

I am loading my android `WebView` using

```
mywebview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", new String(result), "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

HTML rendered successfully in `WebView`. now I want to open another HTML file from that HTML using button for that I am using below code in HTML.

```
<button onclick="location.href='data/1/quiz_adjective.html'" > Start</button>
```

but it does not work. my asset html file directory is - `assets\data\1\htmlfile.html`

Answer (score 0):

When you make Android applications, you can parse HTML data or HTML pages got from the Web by [JSoup](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/learn-to-parse-html-pages-on-android-with-jsoup-2a9b0da0096f) libraly.

Answer (score 0):

Before loading `url` you should enable JS like this. Then, It should work. Or there is a more advanced way with `JavascriptInterface`[docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript)

```
 mywebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```